# What is difference between plus() and put() methods in kotlin map?

Tags: kotlin

What is difference between plus() and put() methods in kotlin map?

I have created the map and use plus() method to add my key value pair but when I print the map, I can't find the added values. And then I have moved to put(). What is the behaviour of plus() method?

Comment: Well + doesn't normally modify its operands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A regular `Map` (which is immutable) can only be modified using the `plus` function (that can also be invoked with the + operator).

The `plus` operator works with pairs of values, and, by nature, does not modify the original map; it returns a new map with the new entry.

```
// mapA and mapB are different maps
val mapA = mapOf("a" to 1, "b" to 2)
val mapB = mapA + ("c" to 3)
```

When using a `MutableMap`, in addition to `plus` (which will still return a new map), there are a few more options to change a map's content: `put`, `set` (which is the [] operator) and `plusAssign` (which is the += operator).

The difference between `set` and `put`, as function calls, is that `put` returns the previous value of the key (or null), whereas `set` does not return anything. Also, when using bracket syntax, you can't use it as a expression body for a function. It's specially useful when creating wrapper classes to access the data inside a map:

```
class SomeWrapper(private val backingMap: MutableMap<String, String?>) {

    var someIntValue: Int?
        get() = backingMap["someInt"]?.toIntOrNull() 
        set(value) = backingMap.set("someInt", value.toString())

        // this is invalid because assignments are not expressions
        // set(value) = backingMap["someInt"] = value

        // this is also invalid because put would return String? instead of Unit
        // set(value) = backingMap.put("someInt", value)

}
```

(of course, in the example above you could just change the setter to use block syntax instead of expression syntax, it's a matter of taste)

The syntax of `plusAssign` is similar to `plus`, but it will change the original map instead:

```
val map = mutableMapOf("a" to 1, "b" to 2)
map += ("c" to 3)
```

Answer (score 10):

As described in [the documentation](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/plus.html), the `plus` method (which is normally used in its operator form, `+`) returns a new map containing the elements from the original map and the key/value pair passed to it as a parameter. It does not modify the map on which it was called.

The idiomatic way to add values to a Kotlin map is not to use the `put` method, but to use square brackets:

```
map[key] = value
```